# Swift 3: failed url request and image not being adding to cell

Tags: uitableview, url, swift3, uiimage

I'm trying to load some pictures from different URL in order to add them to my Table View Cells. Each cell contains an UIImageView and the pictures (UIImage) are not loading correctly.

Sometimes the URL connection fails, and sometimes not. I'm going crazy,
help me please!!

This is the part of my code that tries to download a picture from an specific URL:

```
let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Angels_Stadium.JPG/1920px-Angels_Stadium.JPG")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL as URL) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil, let data = data else { return }

        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)

        self.foto = downloadedImage!

        tableWiew.reloadData()
    }
    task.resume()
```

This code is inside the init function of my class (User). After instantiate the class, I try to add the picture to my tableview in other class like this:

```
let user:User = User(json: obj, tableWiew: self.tableView)
addCell(cell: cell, name: user.nombre, job: user.puesto, nIdeas: "0", mProp: "0", image: user.foto)
```

The "addCell" method just creates a custom cell and inserts it into my tableView. That's working fine except for the damn picture.

If I add a picture from my Assets it works fine, but I don't know what's wrong when I try to add a picture from an URL.

Comment: Have you tried with UrlRequest?? i.e.  let request = URLRequest(url: imageURL!) then  let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in})

Comment: I've tried it, but it returns me "Unable to read data" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download an image inside cellForRowAt method of UITableViewDataSource and if possible use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that will help you with many options eg placeholder. It handles the caching internally and it is async.

Comment: I'm trying to install SDWebImage but I don't know how. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Angels_Stadium.JPG/1920px-Angels_Stadium.JPG")!

    let request = URLRequest(url: imageURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        // print("Task completed")
        // print(response)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
         self.imgVW.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        })

    })
    task.resume()
```